# how can i install the solidity(solc) in ubuntu mate(using raspberry pi3)

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, solidity

I'd like to install a Solidity Compiler on the Raspberry Pi3. But I have no idea how.
the operating system is using Ubuntu Mate.

If there's no way above, could you let me know about Rasbian?

Answer (score 0):

Having Node Package Manager installed:

```
npm install -g solc
```

Comment: You mean you can do this with raspberry pie?

Comment: In Ubuntu. 
But I am Ubuntu mate on Raspberry Pi.
This command is not valid.

Comment: Um, another question,
Can you tell me the difference between solc and solcjs?

Comment: solcjs is the library for JavaScript bindings for the Solidity compiler. `solc` is the name of the program. So you install solcjs do use from Javascript and type `solc` to shell to run it.